# How to truncate a floating point number after a certain number of decimal places (no rounding)?

Tags: c++, c, printf

I'm trying to print the number `684.545007` with 2 points precision *in the sense that the number be truncated (not rounded)* after `684.54`.

When I use

```
var = 684.545007;
printf("%.2f\n",var);
```

it outputs `684.55`, but what I'd like to get is `684.54`.

Does anyone knows how can I correct this?

Comment: If you were expecting `684.54`, then you were expecting the wrong result. It's that simple.

Comment: Because I don't want a rounded value.
This code is part of a Programming Online Judge code solution.

Comment: Again: Rounding doesn't work like you apparently want it to. [Select isn't broken](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html).

Comment: @JackManey, of course not.the number is 684.545 not 684.555. The output should be .54 not .55

Comment: It seems like you have a wrong picture of what "precision" means.

Comment: Another way of putting it: neither 684.54 nor 684.55 is exactly equal to 684.545007, but 684.55 is closer to it, so that's what you get.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What you're looking for is *truncation*. This should work (at least for numbers that aren't terribly large):

```
printf(".2f", ((int)(100 * var)) / 100.0);
```

The conversion to integer truncates the fractional part.

In C++11 or C99, you can use the dedicated function [`trunc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/trunc) for this purpose (from the header `<cmath>` or `<math.h>`. This will avoid the restriction to values that fit into an integral type.

```
std::trunc(100 * var) / 100     // no need for casts
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my approach. It seems ugly but does work in most cases e.g. var can be larger then int, can be zero or bizarre '-0'. It does not handle infinities and NaNs though.

```
double var = 684.545007; // or whatever
double var_trunc = var>=0. ? floor(var*100.)/100. : ceil(var*100.)/100.;
printf ("%g\n", var_trunc);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%.2f\n", var - 0.005);
```

Comment: Since .005 is not representable exactly, this is bound to produce the wrong result for a few values.