# Avoid rounding when inserting double to stringstream

Tags: c++, floating-point, double, rounding

I am using this function to convert a double `f` to string with `p` digits after the decimal point.

```
static std::string doubleToString(double f, int p)
{
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(p) << f;
        std::string s = ss.str();                                   
        s.erase(s.find_last_not_of('0') + 1, std::string::npos);    
        return (s[s.size()-1] == '.') ? s.substr(0, s.size()-1) : s;
}
```

Remaning 0's at the end are erased. For example `1.23000` gets `1.23`.

**Input:**

```
double test1 = 1;
double test2 = 1.12345678;
double test3 = 1.123456789010;

std::cout << doubleToString(test1, 8) << " " << doubleToString(test2, 8) << " " << doubleToString(test3, 8);
```

**Output:**

`1 1.12345678 1.12345679`

As you can see `test1` and `test2` are printed fine. `test3` however gets rounded after the 8'th digit. I'd like to avoid that and "cut" the rest of the number, so that: `doubleToString(1.123456789010, 8)` returns `1.12345678`.

What is the most effective way to do that?

Comment: Why don't you look for `.` and cut everything after `<position of . > + 8`?

Comment: There is a reason why you are depending on exact values in the 8th digit and yet still want to use a floating point type?

Comment: @GMichael I think the rounding is happening at this line: `ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(p) << f;`. Before that, I do not have a string in which I can look for a "." and after that, the string already has the length of `p`. @Warren P yes there is a reason. It has to be exact and floating-point.

Comment: see answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738892/how-to-truncate-a-floating-point-number-after-a-certain-number-of-decimal-places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small modification to your function will do the job; simply put a few extra digits into the stream, and strip them off after the conversion. You need to allow *some* rounding, since binary values might be slightly less than the decimal value you're expecting. In my code below I limit the string conversion to 14 digits, which is about the maximum you can expect from a IEEE double between 1.0 and 10.0; if you expect values larger than this, the algorithm needs to be adjusted since the number of accurate digits after the decimal point will go down.

```
std::string doubleToString(double f, int p)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    int p2 = min(p + 2, 14);
    ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(p2) << f;
    std::string s = ss.str();
    size_t point = s.find('.');
    if (point != std::string::npos && point + 1 + p < s.size())
        s.erase(point + 1 + p);
    s.erase(s.find_last_not_of('0') + 1, std::string::npos);
    return (s[s.size()-1] == '.') ? s.substr(0, s.size()-1) : s;
}
```

See it in action at http://ideone.com/xGoDiH.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
doubleToString( ( test3 - ( 0.5 / ( pow( 10, 8 ) ) ) ), 8 )
```

It's not a clear solution, but should do what you want.

edit:
It just subtract 0.000000005 from your number, so it's not rounded up. You can add it to your function that it will do it with every number:

```
static std::string doubleToString(double f, int p)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(p) << (f - (0.5 / (pow(10, p))));
    std::string s = ss.str();                                   
    s.erase(s.find_last_not_of('0') + 1, std::string::npos);    
    return (s[s.size()-1] == '.') ? s.substr(0, s.size()-1) : s;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'd like to integrate it into the function directly