# How to truncate a randomly generated float to 6 decimals?

Tags: c, random

I wanted to know how to generate Random floating point digits precise upto maximum 6 point decimals and within the range of (-999 to +999) in **C language**

I tried with:

```
unsigned int i, num;
int divide;
FILE *f;

f=fopen("/dev/urandom", "r");
if (!f) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed open file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
for(i=0; i< w*w; i++)
{
    fread(&num, sizeof(unsigned int), 1, f);
    fread(&divide, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    h[i] = ((float)num)/((float)divide);
    
}
fclose(f);
```

But this gives more than 6 decimal points.

Is there a way to get a float no. for eg. 34.123456000000000000000  i.e after 6th decimal place the rest of the value should be truncated.

@sas @Havenard @Lundin  The question marked as duplicate still doesnt  solve the problem. The code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
void fill(float* h, int w)
{
    unsigned int i, num;
    int divide;
    FILE *f;

    f=fopen("/dev/urandom", "r");
    if (!f) 
    {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed open file\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    for(i=0; i< w*w; i++)
    {
        fread(&num, sizeof(unsigned int), 1, f);
        fread(&divide, sizeof(int), 1, f);
        h[i] = ((float)num)/((float)divide);
                h[i] = trunc(100*h[i])/100;   // trial for 2 place decimal
    }
    fclose(f);
} 

void getrand(int n )
{
        const int mybatch = 1;
    float mat1_size = sizeof(float) * n * n;
        float* mat1 = (float*) malloc(mat1_size);
    fill(mat1, n);
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {   
            fprintf(stdout,"%12.10f    ",mat1[i*n+j]);
            
        }
            fprintf(stdout,"\n");
        }
    
        fprintf(stdout,"\n\n");
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc!=2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <matrix_width>\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }

    int w;
    w = atoi( argv[1] );
    
    getrand(w);
        return 0;
}
```

This still prints :

> $ ./a.out 5
>
> -2.2799999714    3.5999999046    15.5200004578    -0.9900000095    -1.3099999428
> -1.8799999952    1.4700000286    2.0499999523    0.4900000095    2.0499999523
> 0.9599999785    -0.4199999869    -0.4499999881    4.3200001717    -0.7699999809
> -2.9300000668    2.5099999905    -1.5900000334    -0.4199999869    -0.6800000072
> -0.2300000042    -1.7599999905    3.1800000668    0.6000000238    0.6000000238

Comment: You haven't tried the *duplicate's* code. That code works with ints to avoid floating point errors. Your code still uses floats which means you still have floating point errors. In any case, random numbers have nothing to do with a *truncation* question. If it isn't this duplicate, it's another duplicate but the technique is the same

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So how do I solve this issue? After your thankful edit.. Is this still a duplicate?

Comment: Yes it is. *Read* the duplicate's code (don't just copy it) and use *it*. It addresses the exact same problem. If you want 6 decimals why do you multiply by 100 (2 decimals)? BTW the answer here even does the proper multiplication/division.

Comment: a different approach: `char r[9] = "0.000000"; r[2] = randto(10) + '0'; /* ... */ r[7] = randto(10) + '0'; sscanf(r, "%f", h) /* or use r directly */;`

Comment: @pmg sorry, but I didn't quite understand

Comment: @pradyot: see [example at ideone](http://ideone.com/YwYkth)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [trunc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/trunc/) function.

Possibly you are looking something like this. Just example.

```
float a = 34.123456000000000000000;
a = trunc(1000000*a)/1000000; 
printf("%f\n", a);// output = 34.123455
```

Note - Please include `math.h` header also in your program

Possible duplicate of [How to truncate a floating point number after a certain number of decimal places (no rounding)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738892/how-to-truncate-a-floating-point-number-after-a-certain-number-of-decimal-places)