# C++ - Truncating decimal places of a double inside a variable filename

Tags: c++, string, fstream

I am trying to write some code to generate appropriate filenames for simulation data. Here, I have created a string, resultfile, which takes text, ints, and doubles and concatenates them into a filename.

Here is my (simplified) current code:

```
string resultfile;
int Nx = 5;
double mu = 0.4;

//Simulation code here

resultfile += to_string(Nx) + "_mu" + to_string(mu) + ".csv"; 
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("./Datasets/"+ resultfile);
myfile << SimulationOutputs;
myfile.close();
```

This saves a .csv file to my /Datasets/ folder, however, the file name of the data ends up as:

"5_mu0.4000000.csv"

When your file title contains 2 or more doubles, the filename becomes obnoxiously large very quickly. I am trying to get the filename to be:

"5_mu0.4.csv"

I found a question that seemed relevant here: [How to truncate a floating point number after a certain number of decimal places (no rounding)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738892/how-to-truncate-a-floating-point-number-after-a-certain-number-of-decimal-places), where they seem to suggest:

```
to_string(((int)(100 * mu)) / 100.0)
```

however, this edit does not change the file name of my data outputs. I am fairly new to C++, so there might be an obvious solution here that isn't obvious to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set precision of `std::to_string`, you might write your own, something like:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

template <typename T>
std::string to_string_with_precision(const T& a_value, const int n = 6)
{
    std::ostringstream out;
    out << std::setprecision(n) << a_value;
    return out.str();
}
```

and then

```
resultfile += std::to_string(Nx) + "_mu" + to_string_with_precision(mu, 2) + ".csv";
```