# Filter Spark DF to column having only 2 decimals without using round/floor

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have spark df as below

```
+-----------+-------+-----+----+----+-------+----+----+-----+
|_c1        |_c2    |_c3  |_c4 |_c5 |_c6    |_c7 |_c8 |_c9  |
+-----------+-------+-----+----+----+-------+----+----+-----+
|10000000001|7982015|0.00 |0   |0.00|12.9912|0.00|1   |0.00 |
+-----------+-------+-----+----+----+-------+----+----+-----+
```

I am trying to trim the column _c6 value to 2 decimals and getting it accurate for which I cannot use round/floor as they give closed values.

Is there a way to pick first two decimals get 12.99 instead of rounding it off?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: multiply by 100, convert to int, then divide by `float(100)`. Possible dupe: [How to truncate a floating point number after a certain number of decimal places (no rounding)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738892/how-to-truncate-a-floating-point-number-after-a-certain-number-of-decimal-places). Also rounding 12.9912 to 2 digits should give you 12.99 - there shouldn't be rounding in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A funny way to do it is to use `regexp_extract` so as to only keep at most 2 digits after the decimal:

```
Seq(8989.09888, 22.1, 88, 345.111)
    .toDF("x")
    .select(regexp_extract('x, "[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]{1,2})?", 0) cast "double" as "x")
    .show
+-------+
|      x|
+-------+
|8989.09|
|   22.1|
|   88.0|
| 345.11|
+-------+
```

Note that we handle all the different cases (no decimal, only one...).

Comment: This will not actually round off. If I am not wrong, for both, 12.9912 and 12.9956 , this will return 12.99.

Comment: You are completely right. Yet I am not sure I fully grasped the question, but from what I understand, it is about truncating, not rounding.

Comment: This worked perfectly, I tried with converting to decimal types and select only 2 decimals that also works