# Prevent over-rounding happening in C++ doubles

Tags: c++, c++11, precision

Have googled a lot about avoiding rounding errors but none of them are solving my case. Need to round off 9.99999975e-05 upto 8 or more precision.

Have tried using stringstream along with setprecision which is pretty much the standard way according to other answers on this site.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(void){

    double val = 9.99999975e-05;
    stringstream tmp;
    tmp << setprecision(8) << fixed << val;
    cout << tmp.str();
    return 0;

}
```

Ideally I would like the result to be 0.00009999
But I am getting 0.00010000 , which I believe is occurring due to rounding off from farthest to most significant '9'.

Any idea how can I stop rounding at 8th precision ?

Comment: Sounds like you want to *truncate* the value. Try searching for *truncating floating point value in C++*

Comment: According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/trunc/ 
'trunc' would strip off complete thing after decimal.

Comment: how about, https://stackoverflow.com/q/12738892/10858827

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you use the `trunc` family of functions, as the truncate to an integer. Instead open your favorite search engine and do some searching about truncating floating point values. You should find quite a lot of links (like the one posted by @Arne).

Comment: @Arne This worked flawlessly for 8 precision. This can be scaled for even greater precision since range of unsigned int ranges to 4 billion.. would it create a problem in arithmetic applied in above mentioned method of yours ? Can you please clear that ?

Comment: Is there any chance you can use a decimal type rather than a binary floating point type? Truncation of the former in decimal representation is tricky; you invariably end up with unexpected results.

Comment: The "scaling" of the method shown by @Arne is the number of digits in the integer type you use. For example using a 32-bit type (like `int` usually is) then you can only go up to 9 digits since the max value of a 32-bit integer is in the range of 10^9. If you want more digits then you have to use 64-bit integers and arithmetic.

Comment: And of course, you will always have the risk of arithmetic overflow. For example, if you have a floating point value a little over `2` and use signed integers you could easily get over the maximum value of a signed 32-bit integer at little over 2 billion. Lastly, remember that double precision floating point numbers (using IEEE754 encoding) only have around 15 significant digits, so using 64-bit arithmetic you can go outside of that (as it's in the 10^19 range).

Answer (score 2):

> Need to round off 9.99999975e-05 upto 8 or more precision. (...)
>    I would like the result to be 0.00009999

Without other test cases I can only guess the OP's intent. So why not truncating the string resulting from the maximum output precision possible?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

int main() 
{
    double val = 9.99999975e-05;
    std::stringstream tmp;
    tmp << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 + 1)
        << std::fixed << val;
    auto repr = tmp.str();

    // Truncate the string
    repr = repr.erase(repr.find('.') + 9);
    std::cout << repr << '\n';             // --> 0.00009999
}
```

I'll also assume that the OP are already aware of [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score -1):

Which platform are you using ? You can try using fesetround api in linux and _controlfp in windows.
I get Value 0.000099999998 on linux when rounding set to zero.
However, i will always recommend using a floating point library for such codes.

Answer (score -3):

For the sake of completeness after going through [How to truncate a floating point number after a certain number of decimal places (no rounding)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738892/how-to-truncate-a-floating-point-number-after-a-certain-number-of-decimal-places) mentioned by @Arne above in comments, here's the changes that I made to above piece of code;

```
double val = 9.99999975e-05;
cout << setprecision(8) << fixed << trunc(100000000 * val) / 100000000;
return 0;
```

Comment: I don't want to depress you but that won't always work. Test it with various `double` values drawn at random.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Testing now.

Comment: To be more accurate, it will fail far more often than it succeeds.